# How do I attach to a running process like a debugger on linux?

Tags: linux, process

What system calls are used? I want to use it to read memory locations scattered inside a different process's address space.  Is this a reasonable use case for this mechanism?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ptrace() is the system call you're looking for.